# Wordpress comment box dissappears after the Disqus plugin (official) is activated

Tags: wordpress, disqus

There are guides online for activating Disqus on Wordpress but nobody seems to have the particular problem which I am having. Previously to installing Disqus I had WP comments and they worked just fine. After activating the Disqus plugin, enabling discussions/comments, and opening comments everywhere, the comment box is gone, not a single trace.

There is simply no trace that Disqus even exists on my website. I don't believe that it is a theme issue because after disabling the theme, no comment boxes are still present.

Has anyone experienced this before? What are some methods I can look for / call in my templates that are supposed to bring up WP items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would always disappear because only one comment system should be there. Anyways, you can get the disqus comment box code and add it at the end of the post. This would make both the comment systems visible and both won't disturb other.